# Gem or Library for scheduled long running jobs in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

Currently in my Rails2 app I'm using BackgroundRb for job queuing and scheduling. However, I've known for a while that because there doesn't appear to be much (any?) activity on maintaining the library the time was coming to replace it with something different.

With the advent of Rails 3 it appears that time is finally here.

I really like the fact that I can schedule jobs and call jobs asynchronously from the same library. In looking at delayed_job it appears that it doesn't have support for the scheduling feature that Brb does.

Am I missing something in DJ? Is there another gem/plugin that supports both mechanisms (scheduling and asyncronous)? What is the method that is commonly used to schedule jobs and still remain DRY?

Answer (score 0):

The new hotness for this sort of thing is [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque), which is an extraction by the github guys. It is really nice, the only thing that may be a stickler is the redis dependency to manage the queue.

Comment: Forgive me if I missed something. I don't see where resque supports scheduled jobs.

Comment: resque has a plugin system, check out https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler